# Send data from JSP to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

Here are my needs :

In a jsp I fill a "table" using javascript (My first "tr" is the titles, the second "tr" is the inputs then all new "tr" are added with a javascript function)

Now I want to send the values of my table to a servlet. **I do not use the jquery framework**

Here is what I've done in js :

```
function test(){
    var strPar= "Blabla BLABLA BLA";
    var toServer = JSONObject.toJSONString(strPar);
    alert("TEST U MF !!!");
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "http://localhost:8084/Calendar/Legal", true);
    request.send(toServer);
    alert("POUET !");
}
```

I doesn't seem to work at all ! Moreover I have no idea on how to get the JSON object from the servlet ?

```
public class LegalCalServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("TEST ");
    String output = request.getParameter("strPar");
    System.out.println(output);

}}
```

I would very appreciate any help on this please !

Comment: First step is check if is a client or server error: Is there any error in the browser console? BTW: You should replace `alert(...)` by `console.log(...)` and check the console instead having popups

Comment: Sorry didn't see your comm.
You are very right about my alert() but I was using it for smtg else and I'm a really lazy guy : copy/paste is my thing ! Haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
 xmlhttp.open("POST","demo_post2.asp",true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

You can check an example and tutorial in this site: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }
 xmlhttp.open("POST","demo_post2.asp",true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
 }
```

Comment: YEAAAAAAAAAAH ! Thx mate ! I wasn't actually instantiate the XMLHttpRequest() !! That's why.
Just need to handle it servlet side now and I'm good :)

Comment: Easy : request.getParameter("lname");

THX DUDE : )

Comment: @Kermit If this answer fits your needings, mark it as the "chosen answer" please :)

Comment: @Pablo I can't do that 'cause I have less than 15 points ...
[Edit] : Ok I'm stupid it's the "tick" we have to click XD

Answer (score 0):

Try adding headers in the request -

Here is an example of Posting data from http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

```
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Comment: Yes I used that for the "GET" method but it didn't work.
I just tried your code and it is not working either ...

Comment: Ok I just copy/paste your code and test it in my project adapting names it just doesn't work ! It stops after the "http.open("POST", url, true);"

Comment: If last alert is not being shown, then the error can be related to security issues... check the browser console (F12 in any browser)

Comment: Btw the error I got was : 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null test.js:20
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange"